# Share multiple files using NppDocShare in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have recently installed NppDocShare plugin in Notepad++. I can share single file at a time in local server. But i want to share multiple file in local network. Is there any way to share multiple files ?
NppDocShare Plugin url: https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppDocShare/